# Firebase "rules" does not work at all

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I made firebase rules as below, but `read` and `write` operations are both available from client.

```
{
    "rules": {
      ".read": false,
      ".write": false
    }
}
```

The Authentication is "Custom".
Could anyone suggest me what is wrong?

### Additional Information

I made iOS client with official Firebase library as below.

```
let firebase = Firebase(url: FIRE_BASE_URL)
    firebase.authWithCustomToken(FIRE_BASE_AUTH_TOKEN) { (error, data) in
        if let data = data {
            debugPrint("***** Log in complete *****")
            let ref = firebase.childByAppendingPath("test/")
            let dic = ["key" : "hoge"]
            ref.childByAutoId().setValue(dic){ (error, firebase) in
                if let key = firebase.key {
                    /* This code reaches here, which is not expected behavior. 
                      (Of course, new data was added to firebase.) */
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add more details. Which node you're trying to read or write. Try sharing some of your code

Comment: @ReazMurshed Thanks for your suggestion, and I added my code.

Comment: Are those the only rules? Check them in your Firebase dashboard. Also, double-check those rules are for whatever FIRE_BASE_URL is.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that `firebase.authWithCustomToken(FIRE_BASE_AUTH_TOKEN)`
must not be called to apply Firebase rules.

This method is only for administration purpose, so any API calls are received after calling this.

Without calling this method, rules worked well.
Thanks.